# Database: image file as blob or file path?

Tags: database, data-structures

I know this question has been asked any a times.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay) whole post but still couldn't reach to a point.

I am making a website which will allow users to download the wallpapers and songs. No one else will upload those wallpapers/songs except me. I mean to say that the users will not be uploading them. At present. Each file on an average is 6Mb(for songs).

Now, what would you prefer to do here? Store them as blob files or use file paths?

Comment: @Scotch And whats your reason for that? because my files are too big?

Comment: I'm honestly just saying it because it's what I'm comfortable doing, and it takes up less space. As a developer for the front end app, I'm more comfortable having the path to my files rather than objects anyways.

Comment: Personally i wouldnt do db, only because in my experience in doing backups and restores with huge dbs,and your db is gonna be huge as you store files as base64 strings and that adds like 1/3 or something to the size of whats being stored, its complicated.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I am very new to all this DataBase stuff. I would follow what you say. So, are you sure that I should go for file paths instead of BLOB?

Comment: Definitely, as it would mean writing more code to get the files in and out of the db otherwise. You could store the paths to the files in the db, that way you can still query the db for like what files go on this page what ones go on that page etc etc, and then just use the path accordingly in your code.

Comment: @PatrickEvans. Well,  again thanks. would like to keep in touch with you . thanks a lot :)

Comment: @PatrickEvans could you refer to me any book/blog regarding this stuff?

Comment: @PatrickEvans I would think that the real issue is not figuring out how to supply a path on demand via an SQL query, but how to restrict unauthorized people from sharing a URL that leads directly to a file (such as one of the songs). Everyone focuses on the image portion of the story, but what about high value downloadable content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In My opinion you should store path in instead of blob. But again it depends upon many other things
- Do you have your own server? or you are hosting it on somewhere else ? Are these things really critical to put as blob in DB ? What will be your backup strategy etc..

I have my own reasoning

- File system is there to manage files and in your case songs and images are not very critical. and imagine if your database will grow in size the performance will go down. If objects are larger than one megabyte on average, NTFS has a clear advantage over SQL Server

Also keep in mind when you have to take backup of your database it may be a big headache at some stage. On the other hand if your songs file are on disk then it will be easy.

Also if you are storing just the path in database, you can consider to keep your songs and picture on some other server (or multiple servers) as well.

In short, I can see many advantages to use file system to store songs and pictures.

Comment: No, i will have my own server. And I m not really sure about the backup strategies.. can you refer to me some book/blog which gives me all such info?

Comment: Sure, as a first step you may refer [microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191239(v=sql.105).aspx)  website. Let me know if you need other help

Comment: Thanks a lot.. i will return back tomorrow after reading that stuff. This is for the first time I would be releasing website. The design part was easy n is already done. Struggling with Database part.

Answer (score 1):

it really depends on what you're doing.

if you use file paths, then you have to have different and consistent security setup on that path.  you also have to do something to enforce unique filenames, etc.  you also need to set up backup for that directory as well

if you use blobs, the database handles security for you, backup should be consistent with everything else in the db.

you might store them as blobs in a different table, with a FK from the first table to the blob table.  then you can avoid storing the same blob multiple times, etc.

Comment: @JohnGardener so you would  prefer to use BLOB regardless of how big the files are?

Comment: like I said, it reaaaaaly depends :)  if this is just for yourself, and you're the only user, it might be simpler to do it as paths + folder.  Do you want to lock down paths though? if it just a file path, you could hypothetically make that visible to the web service and people could directly download the files.  that would simplify that part.

Comment: No, I am not understanding what you are saying. I am pretty new to DataBase things. Could you please refer to me some book/blog where I can readall this stuff from head to toe?

Comment: that's a tall order, a single place where you can read all this from head to toe.  There's no one place to go for your specific needs, or the solution would already exist and you wouldn't have to write it yourself.  there's a whole http://dba.stackexchange.com/ that covers database questions, etc.  there are an infinite number of books+blogs depending on what kind of database you're using.

Comment: @JohnGardner The problem with this issue is that people who want a cheap and fast solution consistently find a way to justify using file paths for all scenarios. However, when confronted with the problem of restricting direct file access (and the problem of people sharing URLs), they have no good answer. Having no answer to this question, strangely enough, circles these types back to promoting the storage of file paths at all costs. They say the database method is too complex. While it does take more planning and coding, it may be the right decision for high value content.

Comment: @JohnGardner Also, most people who blindly justify the file path method tend to use images as their only example. When confronted with what to do in a scenario where a portal separates public users from privileged users, they being the scare tactics surrounding performance, overhead, and backups.

Answer (score 1):

*I found another good answer by [KBrocksi_SEC](http://forums.asp.net/members/KBrocksi_SEC.aspx) in [forum.asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1096999.aspx?Storing%20images%20in%20SQL%20database%20vs%20storing%20images%20in%20seperate%20folder%20and%20using%20URL%20image%20path), so i share it with you:*

A commonly used alternative approach to handling BLOB data is to store the BLOB data in the file system, and store a pointer (preferably a Uniform Resource Locator [URL] link) in a database column to reference the appropriate file.

**Advantages of Storing BLOB Data in the Database**

Storing BLOB data in the database offers a number of advantages:

- It is easier to keep the BLOB data **synchronized** with the remaining items in the row.
- BLOB data is **backed up** with the database. Having a single storage system can ease administration.
- BLOB data can be accessed through **XML support** in SQL Server 2005, which can return a base 64–encoded representation of the data in the XML stream.
- **SQL Server Full Text Search (FTS)** operations can be performed against columns that contain fixed or variable-length character (including Unicode) data. You can also perform FTS operations against formatted text-based data contained within **image** fields—for example, Microsoft Word or Microsoft Excel documents.

**Disadvantages of Storing BLOB Data in the Database**

Carefully consider what resources might be better stored on the file system rather than in a database. Good examples are images that are typically referenced via HTTP HREF. This is because:

- Retrieving an image from a database incurs significant overhead compared to using the file system.
- Disk storage on database SANs is typically more expensive than storage on disks used in Web server farms.

---

The following code shows how to use ADO.NET to write binary data obtained from a file to an **image** field in SQL Server.

```
public void StorePicture( string filename )
{
  // Read the file into a byte array
  using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
  {
    byte[] imageData = new Byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read( imageData, 0, (int)fs.Length );
  }


  using( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString) )
  {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("StorePicture", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@filename", filename );
    cmd.Parameters["@filename"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@blobdata", SqlDbType.Image);
    cmd.Parameters["@blobdata"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    // Store the byte array within the image field
    cmd.Parameters["@blobdata"].Value = imageData;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

---

Also i can add another notes to the above explanations myself:

**Disadvantages of Storing BLOB Data in the Database**

- If your BLOB Data cause a **heavy database** (when you store many files in DB) then the database backup process maybe take more time to complete and cause headaches for you.

Comment: ....and if the database is in a high availability cluster, does your backup concern still matter?

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge, the SQL Server Clustering did not help us to backup heavy databases easier than a database without clusters. It help us to keep the database more online on fail events. On the other hand working with a lighter files always is easier and better than backup and restore heavy files.